# Subsets and roster method

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Write out the following sets by listing their elements between braces.

Let $A=\left\{X\subset \Bbb N||X|=1\right\}$

I think cardinality of $A$ would be countably infinite since each positive natural number would be it's own $X$ set (a singleton) and a subset of the natural numbers with X having cardinality $1$.

Is this correct or off track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. That set is countably infinite. Listed as a roster
$$
A = \{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \ldots \} .
$$